# vs2010 IntelliSense error identifier XXX is undefined

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense, makefile

i have a makefile project which can **build successfully**, but i got a lot of IntelliSense errors like:

`117 IntelliSense: identifier "iInt32" is undefined  d:\project\tjlpad\cpptest\lxn\xmlxn.h   242`

how to config VS2010 to make it can find the code???

--

i'm working on a super old (and not very good) program, which is using VIM&VC++6, i'm trying to use VS2010 to do my development work.

Comment: @CLang i'm asking intellisense errors, not a particular type, u can image a user-defined type named 'uint32' and vs2010 cant find it, but nmake file can.

Comment: @CLang i can have anything they defined...i'm working on a super old (and not very good) program, which is using VIM&VC++6, i'm trying to use VS2010 to do my development work